# SmtpClient time-out on Web. Works in .EXE

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, smtpclient

Help!

I'm having trouble e-mailing from a .NET web application on my local development machine
I have code that works from a .NET command line executable.  However running the same code always "times-out" from the web application.

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, with Windows 7 pro (IIS7), and Visual Studio 2010.

I've turned off all the firewalls etc.

Works in command line.  Does not work (times out on the send call) in ASPX page in the web application.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string strSmtpServer = "theserver";
    string strSmtpUser = "theuser";
    string strSmtpPassword = "thepasswrd";

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient( strSmtpServer);
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( strSmtpUser, strSmtpPassword );

    // Specify the e-mail sender.
    MailAddress from = new MailAddress("customersupport@serenitynow.com" );
    // Set destinations for the e-mail message.
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress("iam@serenitynow.com");
    // Specify the message content.
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.Body = "This is a test e-mail <b>message</b> sent by an application. ";


    message.BodyEncoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    message.Subject = "Mail Test!";
    message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    // Time out exception thrown here on the send call.
    // Waits 60 seconds or so.
    client.Send(message, userState);
    message.Dispose();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.
In IIS, I updated the Application Pool.  Out of the box, it was configured with the "ApplicationPoolIdentity", I switched it over to the "LocalSystem" account, and presto, it works.  The web page can send e-mail now.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a couple of different problems, including DNS registration issues and firewall issues (even though it appears that you have turned them off).

First, on the web machine, open a command prompt and enter 'nslookup theserver' where theserver is the same value you use in your application. If you don't get an IP address, then that is the problem you need to solve.

If you do get an IP address, try pinging the server to see if it is reachable from your machine. If it is not, that is the problem to solve.

If the SMTP server is pingable, try telneting to the server using port 25. If you cannot do this, then there is a firewall or other mechanism that is preventing access.

If this is an external SMTP server, some ISPs block SMTP services on port 25 unless it is going to their SMTP servers.

If you can, and the SMTP server supports it, I would strongly recommend switching to port 587 or 465 to avoid blocking issues. [Here](http://mostlygeek.com/tech/smtp-on-port-587/comment-page-1/) is a handy reference with more information.

Comment: Thanks.  The nslookup gets the proper ip, right away.  The command line program works (sends e-mail) too.  I'm thinking the issue may be a user security issue.  My command line program runs on my ID (Admin), but the .NET Web application runs under something else...